Почему не применяются стили для иконки?
Подключаю Material Icons: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
Хочу иконки сделать более мелкими css:
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 100,
  'GRAD' -25,
  'opsz' 20
}

Использую: <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
Но применяется обычная иконка, почему?
Должно быть так:

Но применяется вот так:



.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 100, 'GRAD' -25, 'opsz' 20
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>




ctrl+shift+r - сброс кеш пробовали? а еще бывает, что следом другой стиль стоит и перебивает, тк стили применяются каскадно

Ничего не работает :(

Он даже тут не работает

начинает работать, если в урле при подключении настройки укажешь, например https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200

Ваши стили применяются, для большей наглядности я добавила зеленый цвет, и он применяется, (сложность именно с параметром font-variation-settings) так как проблема заключается в том, как вы подключаете шрифт.
По-моему, чтобы параметр font-variation-settings мог быть корректно применён, необходимо подключить шрифт в полной вариативной версии, которая поддерживает все параметры, такие как 'wght', 'FILL', 'GRAD' и 'opsz'.
Вот тут интересно
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 100, 'GRAD' -25, 'opsz' 20;
  color: green; 
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>




если надо, чтоб и текст и иконка были, то надо их отдельно делать, тк в вашем случае search отразится только в случае, если иконка не будет найдена.


.icon-with-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: red;
}

.icon {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: green;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="icon-with-text">
  <span class="icon">search</span>
  <span class="text">Search</span>
</div>




обрати внимание, на то, что твой код отличается от кода в вопросе.

@Grundy, это обычно цель ответа, чтоб работало. код отличается порой

Понял, спасибо! Я думал не нужно вписывать параметры эти в шрифт :)

да, через запятую. Там много разных примеров и объяснений интересных (https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols?utm_source=chatgpt.com&hl=ru).
